# Apache authorization using require dbd-group from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, apache, authorization, httpd.conf

I have an app running behind a reverse proxy on Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7.  I am doing authentication using Shibboleth and am currently doing authorization via a whitelist using `AuthGroupFile /path/to/authfile` and `Require group authGroup`.  This currently works with my setup.  I'm trying to change this process to do authorization against a whitelist stored in a SQL Server database, and this is proving to be difficult.

Currently in `conf.d/shib.conf` I have the following:

```
DBDriver odbc
DBDParams "DATASOURCE=ODBCconn,USER=myUser,PASSWORD=myPwd"

<Location /authLocation>
  AuthType shibboleth
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
  Require dbd-group myApp
  AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT appName FROM authTable WHERE UserLogin = %s"
</Location>
```

My with my DSM `ODBCconn` I am using `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` and I can use that DSM to connect using those credentials via pyodbc in python, so I think I have that setup correctly.  In the database, the column `appName` will return the name of the applications the user is authorized to use as stored in `authTable`, or essentially the groups the user is a part of.  Hence, if a user has a row for `myApp` they will be authorized to use `myApp`.  My understanding of the documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_dbd.html) is this is how my query should work for defining a group.

However, when running this I get a `stack smashing error` in my httpd/logs/error_log that looks something like:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/sbin/httpd terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
...
...
Long long list of files
...
...
[Thu Jan 28 09:36:53.306151 2021] [core:notice] [pid 10621] AH00052: child pid 24810 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Thu Jan 28 09:36:53.306215 2021] [core:notice] [pid 10621] AH00052: child pid 28192 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Thu Jan 28 09:36:53.306238 2021] [core:notice] [pid 10621] AH00052: child pid 31928 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Any help on what might be going wrong with my setup that is preventing authorization in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has a similar issue, I was finally able to solve the problem myself.

My Apache Version was 2.4.6 but the most recent RHEL Version, httpd-2.4.6-97.el7.centos I believe.  Looking at the Change Log for apache 2.4 (https://www.apachelounge.com/Changelog-2.4.html) most of the `mod_authz_dbd` changes were included in the CentOS version except for the one integrated in Apache 2.4.17 entitled

```
*) mod_authz_dbd: Avoid a crash when lacking correct DB access permissions. 
PR 57868. [Jose Kahan < jose w3.org>, Yann Ylavic]
```

Interestingly, this type of crash seemed to similarly describe the type of crash I was observing, though my DB access permissions were correct.

I followed the instructions here (https://crosp.net/blog/administration/install-latest-apache-server-centos-7/) to install Apache 2.4.46.  Getting this updated version of Apache solved my problem using the exact same `.conf` file listed above.  Unfortunately, my Apache now doesn't have the benefits of RHEL if I go this route, but I'm assuming this bug fix in Apache 2.4.17 is tied to the error I was seeing.

Either way, I figured it was worth mentioning the solution I was able to obtain in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.